# Dividing values from two columns in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, division

I have a gridview displaying the quantity of a product and and their total price. I want to add another column which display the price of 1 item i.e. dividing the total price with the quantity. How can I do this please?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    onrowdatabound="grdDetails_RowDataBound" BorderColor="White">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDetailsId" HeaderText="Code" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Description" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Qty" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="Price" />                                                        
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may evaluate binding expression in markup by adding TemplateField.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Literal 
       ID="Literal4" 
       runat="server" 
       Text='<%# (Decimal.Parse(Eval("TotalPrice").ToString())/Decimal.Parse(Eval("Quantity").ToString())).ToString("N2") %>'>
    </asp:Literal>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```